# Converting text to images using the huggingface API

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface

I have some code like:

```
from huggingface_hub.inference_api import InferenceApi

inference = InferenceApi(repo_id="hakurei/waifu-diffusion")
output = (inference("masterpiece, best quality, upper body, 1girl, looking at viewer, red hair, medium hair, purple eyes, demon horns, black coat, indoors, dimly lit"))
print(output)
output.show()
```

I confuse why return image are always same. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

if you are getting same image for same prompt it's quit normal try changing the seed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35223972)